# Visual C++ CEdit Control - Why is the Insertion Point changed by SetWindowText()

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

The following snippet is from the OnChange() handler of a multiline CEdit control, which has "WantReturn" set.

```
void DLG::OnChangeEditPrepareTape() 
{
    CString ss;
    std::vector<char> aTape;
    m_prepareTape.GetWindowText(ss);
    m_prepareTape.SetWindowText(ss);
}
```

If the SetWindowText() is commented out, the user’s text builds up on the right, and all is well.  But, with it in,  the text insertion point moves to the left edge, and the user’s characters go in to the left of the existing characters..

I want to put some tinkering text between the two calls, and can get what I want by subclassing CEdit.  But I’d be interested  to know if there is a way of doing it by Get() & Set().

I’m using Visual C++ 6, with Service Pack 5.  Eleven years old now, but then “Software does not wear out” as they say:-).

Answer (score 2):

The insertion point is reset by `SetWindowText()` because, from the control's point of view, its whole text content has just been reset (possibly to the empty string), and both the insertion point and the current selection might not be meaningful enough to keep them around.

You can use [GetSel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hyt7tyx.aspx) and [SetSel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9kftda4.aspx) to implement this behavior yourself:

```
void DLG::OnChangeEditPrepareTape() 
{
    CString ss;
    std::vector<char> aTape;

    int start, end;
    m_prepareTape.GetSel(start, end);
    m_prepareTape.GetWindowText(ss);

    // Tinker with the text...

    m_prepareTape.SetWindowText(ss);
    m_prepareTape.SetSel(start, end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you use `GetSel` to retrieve the cursor position before you replace the text, and `SetSel` to place it in the same location afterwards.

```
void DLG::OnChangeEditPrepareTape() 
{
    CString ss;
    int start, stop;
    std::vector<char> aTape;
    m_prepareTape.GetWindowText(ss);
    m_prepareTape.GetSel(&start, &stop);
    m_prepareTape.SetWindowText(ss);
    m_prepareTape.SetSel(start, stop);
}
```

If you modify the text before you put it back in the text box, you can increment or decrement `start` (and `end`) accordingly.